# How to convert system usernames to lower case in pg_ident.conf

Tags: postgresql

I have a map defined in the `pg_ident.conf` file on a PostgreSQL 13.6 cluster:

```
# MAPNAME    SYSTEM-USERNAME    PG-USERNAME
dir          /^(.*)$            \1
```

But the system user "John" can indifferently login with either `JOHN` or `john`, so for the moment I must have both defined in my `pg_user` table in order to allow John to login to the databases whatever version of his system username he used.

Is there a way (e.g. a regex?) to **only** have lowercase pg users in the database cluster, and to force incoming system usernames to be *lower-cased* in the `pg_ident.conf` file?

Comment: I have same need :S

Comment: Postgres' regular expressions seem to allow "embedded options"; according to [this](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/functions-matching.html#POSIX-SYNTAX-DETAILS) `/(?i)^(.*)$` should make the match case-insensitive, perhaps you could try it.